# OpenShift Invalid certificate | SSL on NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, ssl-certificate, openshift

Here's what I'm working with:

- NodeJS/Express app
- OpenShift environment (Enterprise account)
- Works over HTTP
- Certificate trust error over HTTPS
- Using default wildcard certificate provided by OpenShift
- Begins working if I go manually accept the exception the browsers are raising
- Latest Express

Server.js looks something like:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    IP = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1",
    PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8888; // its 8080 on openshift.  i use 8888 only on my local environment for irrelevant reasons


// we sometimes need special endpoints that arent files
app.get("/something-special", function(req, res) {
  res.send("something special");
});

// but typically it's static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


// go!
app.listen(PORT, IP);
```

When I go to https://myserver/file.js (which lives in /public/file.js), I get an error saying the certificate is not trusted.

I dont much understand certificates, and I barely know Node.  This is a learning project so I'm trying to work through all of the issues I come across without changing course.

I've tried everything I can think of, including:

- app.enable('trust store') recommended on a different SO
- simplifying my Node app and using req.secure to force HTTPS

Answer (score 3):

You might try visiting your app using the https://appname-yourdomainname.rhcloud.com/ version of the URL.  The underlying digital certificate is *.rhcloud.com and was issued by "Geotrust SSL CA" for what it's worth.  If you do it this way you don't get certificate-related errors because they applied a wildcard-based cert to the servers.

I'm not sure that the free version of the hosting allows for private SSLs to be provided/bound...  Yeah, you need Bronze or better to allow a private SSL for your application.  [Bummer](https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing)

Comment: Nice answer.  You would have to upgrade to the Bronze tier to be able to install a custom ssl certificate.

Comment: It should be noted (because it may not be clear from their web page) that the Bronze tier is still free unless you use more than the 3 gears (what you had with the free tier). Custom SSL use is free.

Comment: Ill try this tomorrow. We're not using the free version.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely what is happening is that you are trying to use the *.rhcloud.com wildcard ssl certificate with your custom domain, and that won't work.  OpenShift supplies you with an ssl certificate that matches your app-domain.rhcloud.com address.  if you want to use SSL correctly with your custom domain, then you need to acquire (or purchase) a custom ssl certificate for your domain name.  You can get one at lots of companies online, or you can get a free on here: https://www.startssl.com

Also, the SSL is terminated on the proxy, before it gets to your gear.  Check out this developer center article for more information about how it all works: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Comment: I can't say what the real domain is, but say it was Gorilla. The cert is signed to *.ose.gorilla.com. My app is gorilla-zoo.ose.gorilla.com.

Comment: If you view the details of the certificate when you get the error, what is the specific reason it lists for not being valid? Without the real domain/error, it's hard to give you a better idea of the issue.  If you want you can use the contact form at help.openshift.com to give me the real domain.